# QSortFilterProxyModel is used with the wrong index

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

I am using the a `QSortFilterProxyModel` to sort a `QFileSystemModel`, but when choosing an index, it is said the wrong index `QSortFilterProxyModel: index from wrong model passed to mapFromSource deleting item`

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import os
import shutil

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        le = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(textChanged=self.on_textChanged)
        self.lv = QtWidgets.QListView()
        self.lv.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QListView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.lv.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.lv.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.showContextMenu)


        self._dirpath = r'C:\Documents\notebooks'

        self.file_model = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
        self.file_model.setRootPath(r'C:\Documents\notebooks')
        self.file_model.setFilter(QtCore.QDir.NoDotAndDotDot 
            | QtCore.QDir.AllEntries 
            | QtCore.QDir.Dirs 
            | QtCore.QDir.Files)
        self.proxy_model = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel(
            recursiveFilteringEnabled=True,
            filterRole=QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel.FileNameRole)
        self.proxy_model.setSourceModel(self.file_model)
        self.lv.setModel(self.proxy_model)
        self.adjust_root_index()

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(le)
        lay.addWidget(self.lv)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def on_textChanged(self, text):
        self.proxy_model.setFilterWildcard("*{}*".format(text))
        self.adjust_root_index()

    def adjust_root_index(self):
        root_index = self.file_model.index(self._dirpath)
        proxy_index = self.proxy_model.mapFromSource(root_index)
        print(self.file_model.filePath(root_index))
        self.lv.setRootIndex(proxy_index)
        
    def showContextMenu(self, point):
        ix = self.lv.indexAt(point)
        if ix.column() == 0:
            menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
            menu.addAction("Action 1")
            action = menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(point))
            if action:
                if action.text() == "Action 1":
                    ppath = os.path.normpath(self.file_model.filePath(self.proxy_model.mapFromSource((ix))))
                    print(ppath) # the problem is in here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Typo: change to `self.proxy_model.mapToSource(ix)` (you are getting the index of the proxy, you have to map it **to** the source).

Comment: YES, Thank you, i was missing that